# Can a three digit number start with zero?

Tags: puzzle

This is a viral so-called brain teaser where it mentions that the numeric lock is a **three digit** key. If we solve it using the hints you'll arrive at the answer 042, which is where I'm a little concerned, since I believed a three digit number mustn't start with zero. I understand the puzzle may've used a different definition of digit where it may simply have considered digits to be numeric numbers 0,1,..,9. What I want to know whether it's correct to do so. Thank you! [Image link is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKLQl.jpg)

Comment: I'm pretty sure a three digit number doesn't start with a $0$, but if you go by these kind of riddles, each slot can be a digit from $ 0 - 9 $, so $042$ might be an answer.

Comment: I do not think that "three digit key" and "three digit number" mean the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A three digit key is not a number, or even a numeral. It is simply a string of three digits.

Answer (score 1):

The typical base $10$ representation of numbers is frequently not unique though the problem is seen less often with integers.  Are these numbers different: $1, 1.0, 1.00$?  How about $.5, 0.5, 0.50$?

Similar, $042$ is an unusual way to write $42$ but it still the same number.

In some contexts, this unusual representation is common.  Look at the odometer in a car.  Mine currently says $099950$ so soon it won't start with a $0$ but it has for the last $18$ years. Numerical locks are another case in which this is common.  It is also common with times in $24$ hour notation e.g. 09:30.